# Squid: * connect to ipaddress port 3128 failed: Connection refused

Tags: server, proxy

I'm setting up a proxy server with squid.

After all the steps, I restarted with
`sudo systemctl restart squid.service`
which returned:
`active`.
I then attempted to test the connection:

```
curl -v -x http://your_squid_username:your_squid_password@ipaddress:3128 http://www.google.com/
```

This error was the result:

> Trying ipaddress:3128...
> connect to ipaddress port 3128 failed: Connection refused
> Failed to connect to ipaddress port 3128 after 1 ms: Connection refused
> Closing connection 0
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to ipaddress port 3128 after 1 ms: Connection refused

The configuration file `/etc/squid/squid.conf` has these settings:

```
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
acl localnet src ipaddress
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
#http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow authenticated

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all
```

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-squid-proxy-on-ubuntu-20-04). Everything went well until the start of Step 3 when I used `curl` to test the squid connection.

Is there anything in the `squid.conf` that needs to be changed? How do you fix this?

Comment: Well, have a look at the Squid logs and see if they give you any clues. They should be available under /var/log/squid.

Comment: There are two files under that folder `access.log` and `cache.log`. Both of them are blank.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the IP address that appears on ip2location.com or similar sites, the `ipaddress` should be either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. The command should then be `curl -v -x http://your_squid_username:your_squid_password@127.0.0.1:3128` or `curl -v -x http://your_squid_username:your_squid_password@localhost:3128`

Comment: I actually managed to get get the status to `active`. Is this exclusive to squid users and not paid ISP proxies? I'm new to working with servers, sorry in advance if this question is very basic.